# Making sprites inside/outside of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've got all my code working on its own. I need to start linking it all to buttons though.

QUESTION: trying to setup multiple buttons as sprites for collision purposes. Don't know how to do it outside of a class.

I have buttons working in seperate classes, but cannot get them to work in the same class for the obvious reason of, the self.image of the second one is overwriting the first one.

```
class Icons(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, *args):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, *args)

    self.image = pygame.image.load("images/airbrushIC.gif").convert()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    ic1 = self.image
    self.rect.x = 50
    self.rect.y = 490

    self.image = pygame.image.load("images/fillIC.gif").convert()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    ic2 = self.image
    self.rect.x = 10
    self.rect.y = 540


def update(self):
    pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
```

This code doesn't have to be a class. But I do not know how to make the images a sprite without being inside of a class. Any help would be appriciated thanks!

Comment: An `Icons` shouldn't be a `Sprite`. It represents a set of sprites. Either remove the `Sprite` superclass, and hold sprite instances, or make a class for a single icon.

Comment: See also: Sprite groups, which hold lists of sprites and have related functions. http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Icons you should have a generic Icon class.
Then you can create an instance of Icon for each button.

```
class Icon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_name, pos, cb, cb_data, *args):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, *args)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/" + image_name).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = pos[0]
        self.rect.y = pos[1]

        this.cb = cb              # function to call when button is pressed
        this.cb_data = cb_data    # data to pass to the function

    def pressed():
        this.cb(cb_data)
```

Then in you main function you create the buttons:

```
ic1 = Icon("airbrushIC.gif", (50, 490), button_pressed, "airbrushIC")
ic2 = Icon("fillIC.gif", (10, 540), button_pressed, "fillIC")
buttons = [ic1, ic2]

def button_pressed(data):
    print "Button pressed:" + str(data)
```

Last, for every mouse down event you look for a button collition:

```
for b in buttons:
    if b.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
         b.pressed()
```